# Popup not dismissed during animation

Tags: bug, status-declined, tags, stack-exchange

When you hover over a tag the regular way, a popup is shown. Once you mouseout, the popup is then dismissed.

However, if you hover over the tag and then mouseout during the popup animation the popup does not get dismissed. I think this does not only apply to Stack Overflow, but also any other Stack Exchange site.

I have only been able to test this in Google Chrome and Firefox.

I know this is just a small matter, but is this intended at all? If so, why would anyone want this kind of functionality?

Comment: But I noticed that **after** this happens once, it does not repeat itself.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA What do you mean it does not repeat itself? If you make it happen, make the popup disappear, it will happen again when trying, at least for me, in Google Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I am agreeing with you. just it only happens once.

Answer (score 1):

<del>It seems to have been fixed, so I am marking as completed.</del>

---

It only happens if you don't wait for the animation to start. I'll see what I can do.

---

It's not trivial to fix but it's a really minor bug, declining.

Comment: I can still reproduce it on this very question. You have to hover on a tag for a fraction of a second, then move the cursor away as soon as the tooltip animation starts, then the tooltip stays there even though the cursor is away from the tag.

Comment: Ok, I can't repro then (I really tried)

Comment: [Here you go](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4fVdaQfqSMU). (maybe browser related? Chrome here)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think this happens because there is a delay before the tooltip shows up, so the `mouseout` event cannot be triggered properly during that time. In short, not enough jQuery.

Comment: I can also reproduce it. Chrome over Ubuntu.

Comment: Got it. this only happens if you move the mouse *before* the animation starts

Comment: @Sklivvz well, you can always decline as too minor. :)