# Tag popups appear when scrolling but not hovering

Tags: bug, tags, user-interface

On Chrome Version 28.0.1500.95, Mac OSX 10.7.5, I click on 'Unanswered Questions' and two-finger scroll to browse the questions. Naturally, if the scrolling action causes a tag to slide up under the mouse, a popup will appear. This happens often enough to be annoying, so now I'm in the habit of moving my mouse off to the left of the questions to prevent popups. Even then, at random times, a tag popup will appear anyway.

***Edit:*** Here's a [video](http://youtu.be/UXCYK9x4YwY). Watch for a flicker at about 42s, and the big payoff at 52s. Notice at the beginning that I move the mouse way over to the left.

Here's a screen shot, but Mac screen shots don't include the mouse(!), so the video is more useful. Has anyone else seen this?

[image]

***Edit***: I also notice lately that while doing all this, the subject links for the questions sometimes go active (with an underline) as though I had hovered the mouse over them. This happens independently from the popups. Not sure whether this is new behavior or I simply just started to notice it.

***Edit:*** Also, some details about my usage that might be relevant:

1. I click on 'Unanswered' and 'newest'
2. I scroll through the questions
3. When I see an interesting one, I cmd+click on it to open the link in a new tab
4. I use option+cmd+rightcursor to move to the new window.
5. When I'm done with that question, I use cmd+w to close that window, which returns me to the page of unanswered questions.
6. Repeat from step 2

I haven't noticed yet whether the popups and underlining occur only after I do the above steps.

Comment: It's all about timing and not related to scrolling. Just hover enough time to "activate" the popup then hover away split of a second before it actually opens and you get what you described. [Reproduced](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eFspHxEVx1Q). :)

Comment: No, this is not the same as what your video shows. My mouse is to the left of the questions the whole time while I'm scrolling. I've meticulously reproduced it many times, although it is quite random.

Comment: I had this issue too: Sometimes I would get a tag popup open, even if I was simply scrolling a list of questions, without hovering the mouse over the popups. Maybe I have reported it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Popup not dismissed during animation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145288/popup-not-dismissed-during-animation)

Comment: @Xufox Not the same bug, as per the reply to Shadow's comment.