# Tag and reputation popups are visible simultaneously

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, profile-page

Due to timeout before showing the tag popup on the [activity tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity) of the user profile page you can see the simultaneously appearance of both popups. Here are the gif and stop-frame:

> [image: gif]

> [image: stop-frame]

Comment: I don’t see how this is a bug. What possible fix would you suggest?

Comment: @Xufox in normal case when you leave a mouse pointer away from [tag] popup disappears.

Comment: But you can reproduce this without the “Reputation gained” pop-up.

Comment: @Xufox then you won't see the second popup :)

Comment: Same basic bug: [Popup not dismissed during animation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145288/289905).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is that unexpected far as behavior goes. It's also not unusable, unless I suppose you really wanted to read the tag info... but in that case, wait for the popover to appear. :)